# What is the difference between the "scope" and the "on-topic" tags on most child metas?

Tags: discussion, tags, off-topic, per-site-meta, scope

In most sites I participate, their child metas have simultaneously two seemingly similar tags: [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) (or [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic), [on-topic-ness](/questions/tagged/on-topic-ness), [off-topic-ness](/questions/tagged/off-topic-ness)). Is this redundant? If yes, shouldn't we automatically merge them together?

Explanation of the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag of MSE:

> **Use this tag when examining what is on-topic or off-topic, and why.**
>
> [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) is used to define what is pertinent to discussion. Generally, the scope determines what the site is about. Issues arising from [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) might have to do with whether a certain question is on-topic or not, but also can be used to evaluate whether an entire topic should be up for discussion (especially as it pertains to specific Stack Exchange sites).
>
> Using this tag indicates that the question is requesting help with scope (normally as a specific use of a general topic), and answers should generally relate to the scope of the site and whether the topic raised generally relates. It also may be the case where a user has a question, but doesn't know where it belongs.

Explanation of the [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) tag of MSE:

> This tag is for questions regarding off topic questions, including whether a question is on topic and what to do with off topic questions.

Comment: We recently synonymized those at [meta.webapps.se].

Comment: They have been synonyms from the beginning on Retrocomputing.SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think they can be synonymized. One could argue that the second part of [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic),

> what to do with off topic questions

is not necessarily related to discussion about the scope of a site, but since the answer is just 'close them', retagging to [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) would work.

Note that on Meta Stack Exchange, [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) is already a synonym of [scope](/questions/tagged/scope), and on Meta Stack Overflow, [on-topic] and [off-topic] already map to [[scope]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/scope/synonyms) as well.

The problem with tag synonyms is that they are **slow**. Not many people visit the  ['review queue'](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) for these, and you need some score in one of the tags to vote on them. On Meta sites, it's even worse. <s>I'm pretty active here, but somehow I just have a score of 3 in [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) so I can't create or vote on a synonym.</s> I've just suggested a tag synonym, you can vote for it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/scope/synonyms) if you have a score of 5 or more in the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag.

Most synonyms are created by ♦ moderators nowadays, who can create them single-handedly. However, since this is an issue on *all* Meta sites, each with their own moderators, this will either require a massive coordinated effort, or one of the Stack Overflow employees (who have ♦ powers on all sites) needs to think this is a big enough problem to fix it at once.